# Stop a function if the function got new value

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I need help with my javascript function

If a user clicks an element with this event listener...

`onmousedown="down('+j+')"`

This function recieves 'j' as a callback...

```
function down(j) {
mousedown = true;
mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    if(mousedown) {
        $('#del'+j).show();
        $('#ed'+j).show();
        $('#clock'+j).hide();
        $('#doneButton'+j).show();
        navigator.vibrate(50);
    }
}, 300);
```

}

I'm trying to run this function if the value of 'j' has changed...

```
function doneEditDel(d){
$('#doneButton'+d).hide();
$('#del'+d).hide();
$('#ed'+d).hide();
$('#clock'+d).show();
}
```

The 'onmousedown' listener is attached to buttons with different values. So, if the user clicks another button, with a different value, the current function is still being executed. I want run function doneEditDel if 'onmousedown' listener with the other value execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the previous value and check it within your down function

```
var prevJ = null;

function down(j) {
if(prevJ !== null && prevj !== j) {
  clearTimeout(mousedown_timer);
  doneEditDel(j) // I think that is what you wanted to happen
  return;
}
prevJ = j;

mousedown = true;
mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    if(mousedown) {
        $('#del'+j).show();
        $('#ed'+j).show();
        $('#clock'+j).hide();
        $('#doneButton'+j).show();
        navigator.vibrate(50);
    }
}, 300);
```

Comment: if i do this code..the other button that will send same function cant send the value anymore..

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to cancel the timer that you create in the down function. If so, you'd need to make the timer variable accessible to the doneEditDel function by making it, for example, global. You can then clear the timer by calling clearTimeout(mousedown_timer) in doneEditDel.

Comment: no its not. the timer i create is for user if the user hold the button1 then then other button1small will show.the problem is if button2 clicked(send the same function with button1) i want the button1small 'hide' which is the function is doneEditDel. sorry for bad epxplantion

Answer (score 0):

```
var prevJ = null;

function down(j) {
if(prevJ !== null && prevJ !== j) {
doneEditDel(prevJ); // I think that is what you wanted to happen
}
prevJ = j;
mousedown = true;
mousedown_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    if(mousedown) {
        $('#del'+j).show();
        $('#ed'+j).show();
        $('#clock'+j).hide();
        $('#doneButton'+j).show();
        navigator.vibrate(50);

    }
}, 300);

}
```

after some hardtime with the idea from code above..i solved it..thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the problem all together by [debouncing](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the `down()` function. This will effectively cancel the previous call to a function if the function is called again within a specified time frame.

See the snippet using the debounce implementation from the referenced article. Click A and wait 2 seconds and it will hide. Click A then B within 2 seconds and B will hide after 2 seconds:

```js
function down(event) {
  //no need for timeout
  $(event.target).hide();
}

var debouncedDown = debounce(down, 2000); //create instance to use across handlers

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Button A" id="button-a" onmousedown="debouncedDown(event)" />
<input type="button" value="Button B" id="button-b" onmousedown="debouncedDown(event)" />
```